# why does my index match formula with an nested indirect reference return as a #REF... perrrrplexed

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

here is the formula:

```
INDEX(INDIRECT(M$8&"!BS:BS"),MATCH($B11,INDIRECT(M$8&"!B:B"),0))
```

the output for M$8 is week 1_mon

the formula within M$8 is "week 1_"&M10

the output for M10 = mon

I checked that the text for the name of sheet is the same as the output for M$8. The result was "TRUE".

I am perplexed!!

Comment: First, try entering the formula manually and see what it looks like. There is an obvious problem with the sheet name "week 1_mon".

Comment: @SJR here is the formula without the indirect reference. it works like a charm!

=INDEX('week 1_mon'!BS:BS,MATCH($B14,'week 1_mon'!B:B,0))

Comment: See Rory's answer to see what I was getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes round the sheet name because it has a space in it, so:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&M$8&"'!BS:BS"),MATCH($B11,INDIRECT("'"&M$8&"'!B:B"),0))
```